# Did anyone tried to add React UI to KeystoneJS v6 for custom page?

Tags: next.js, antd, keystonejs6

Took a while to lookup the keystone config, seems no way to addon to _app.js for the Admin NextJS app

Comment: Have you seen the Custom Admin UI Pages guide (https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/custom-admin-ui-pages)? It walks though how to do this. You don't need to modify `_app.js`. There's also an example project here: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/examples/custom-admin-ui-pages

Comment: Thz Molomby, I did read through the Custom Admin UI Pages and tried out. What exactly I would like to do it adding "Ant Design" or other similar UI components for those custom page. Those require importing something in _app.js as global CSS import.

Answer (score 0):

This is a current limitation of Admin UI customisation - if changes need to be made in `_app.tsx` or `_document.tsx` it can’t be done. The team's aware of it and there's been a lot of internal discussion about how the Admin UI could be improved. This all falls under "next-gen Admin UI" mentioned on the [roadmap](https://keystonejs.com/updates/roadmap).